# SDL Web 8 Installation Timeout Expired

Tags: web8, installation, sdl-tridion

I am facing timeout expire issue while installing Web 8 and below is the message I am getting after specify Database details during installation wizard.

*"SDL Web 8
Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=21021;handshake=1;"*

Please let me know how we can increase the timout value for the installation.

Answer (score 4):

By looking at the error message I could say it is not a single machine installation of Web 8. The error message is indicating that your web server is not able to connect with your SQL server instance. Some of the common reason for this kind of issue are:

- TCP/IP for both IPV4 or IPV6 is not enabled on the web server.
- Firewall is blocking the inbound port 1433(Default one).

It is not specific to Web 8 and if above point is not useful you can take help of google by searching the part of error message(`[Pre-Login] initialization=21021;handshake=1`).

Comment: Thanks Mukesh to provide the pointers & on your queries, Yes we have database installed on separate server. 1. We have already enabled database TCP/IP settings on database server instead of enabling them on Web Server and that's why we were able to install CMS & Topology database from the CMS server using PowerShell script. But we had not unblock inbound port 1433 from the database server and that's the reason CMS installer is not able to connect SQL Server and throws timeout error.

Comment: That's great. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 3):

In order to fix mentioned Time-Out error coming up from the CMS installer. We need to unblock 1433 port and TCP/IP & Named Pipes protocol under SQL Server Configuration Manager should be enabled on database server.